# Not-reproducible results using IPOPT in C#

Tags: c#, optimization, ipopt

I am currently trying to implement an optimization problem in C# using [IPOPT](https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt) and [csipopt](https://github.com/cureos/csipopt).

I observed that running the same problem with the same data over and over in the same process leads to different results every time. Among others, the cpu time keeps increasing in the log files, and the initial IPOPT heading is only printed in the first log file. However, if I stop and restart the process, results are reproducible (i.e. iteration 0 is the same every time, iteration 1 too, etc.).

First iteration logs:

```
List of options:

                                    Name   Value                # times used
              acceptable_constr_viol_tol = 0.01                      1
                 acceptable_dual_inf_tol = 1e+010                    1
                         acceptable_iter = 15                        1
               acceptable_obj_change_tol = 1e+020                    1
                          acceptable_tol = 1e-006                    1
                             alpha_for_y = primal                    1
                  bound_mult_init_method = constant                  1
                     bound_mult_init_val = 1                         1
                           compl_inf_tol = 0.0001                    2
                         constr_viol_tol = 0.0001                    2
                            dual_inf_tol = 1                         1
                   hessian_approximation = limited-memory            3
                                max_iter = 50                        1
                                 mu_init = 1                         1
                             mu_strategy = monotone                  2
                           mumps_scaling = 77                        3
                nlp_scaling_max_gradient = 100                       1
                                recalc_y = no                        1
                       recalc_y_feas_tol = 1e-006                    0
                                     tol = 1e-008                    2

******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
 Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
         For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
******************************************************************************

NOTE: You are using Ipopt by default with the MUMPS linear solver.
      Other linear solvers might be more efficient (see Ipopt documentation).


This is Ipopt version 3.11.0, running with linear solver mumps.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:        0
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:       10
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:        0

Hessian approximation will be done in the space of all 9 x variables.

Scaling parameter for objective function = 1.000000e+000
objective scaling factor = 1
No x scaling provided
No c scaling provided
No d scaling provided
DenseVector "original x_L unscaled" with 9 elements:

[...]

Calling MUMPS-1 for symbolic factorization at cpu time      0.012 (wall      0.003).
Done with MUMPS-1 for symbolic factorization at cpu time      0.012 (wall      0.003).
MUMPS used permuting_scaling 5 and pivot_order 5.
           scaling will be 77.
Calling MUMPS-2 for numerical factorization at cpu time      0.012 (wall      0.003).
Done with MUMPS-2 for numerical factorization at cpu time      0.012 (wall      0.003).
Number of doubles for MUMPS to hold factorization (INFO(9)) = 31
Number of integers for MUMPS to hold factorization (INFO(10)) = 164
Calling MUMPS-3 for solve at cpu time      0.012 (wall      0.003).
Done with MUMPS-3 for solve at cpu time      0.012 (wall      0.003).
```

Second iteration logs:

```
List of options:

                                    Name   Value                # times used
              acceptable_constr_viol_tol = 0.01                      1
                 acceptable_dual_inf_tol = 1e+010                    1
                         acceptable_iter = 15                        1
               acceptable_obj_change_tol = 1e+020                    1
                          acceptable_tol = 1e-006                    1
                             alpha_for_y = primal                    1
                  bound_mult_init_method = constant                  1
                     bound_mult_init_val = 1                         1
                           compl_inf_tol = 0.0001                    2
                         constr_viol_tol = 0.0001                    2
                            dual_inf_tol = 1                         1
                   hessian_approximation = limited-memory            3
                                max_iter = 50                        1
                                 mu_init = 1                         1
                             mu_strategy = monotone                  2
                           mumps_scaling = 77                        3
                nlp_scaling_max_gradient = 100                       1
                                recalc_y = no                        1
                       recalc_y_feas_tol = 1e-006                    0
                                     tol = 1e-008                    2
This is Ipopt version 3.11.0, running with linear solver mumps.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:        0
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:       10
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:        0

Hessian approximation will be done in the space of all 9 x variables.

Scaling parameter for objective function = 1.000000e+000
objective scaling factor = 1
No x scaling provided
No c scaling provided
No d scaling provided
DenseVector "original x_L unscaled" with 9 elements:

[...]

Calling MUMPS-1 for symbolic factorization at cpu time      0.289 (wall      0.279).
Done with MUMPS-1 for symbolic factorization at cpu time      0.289 (wall      0.279).
MUMPS used permuting_scaling 5 and pivot_order 5.
           scaling will be 77.
Calling MUMPS-2 for numerical factorization at cpu time      0.289 (wall      0.279).
Done with MUMPS-2 for numerical factorization at cpu time      0.289 (wall      0.279).
Number of doubles for MUMPS to hold factorization (INFO(9)) = 31
Number of integers for MUMPS to hold factorization (INFO(10)) = 164
Calling MUMPS-3 for solve at cpu time      0.289 (wall      0.279).
Done with MUMPS-3 for solve at cpu time      0.289 (wall      0.279).
```

My guess is that some resource is not released when disposing my problem, and some values are kept somewhere in memory. This becomes more of a problem as my problem sometimes converges, sometimes does not with the same data.

My problem is constructed as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Cureos.Numerics;

namespace Ipopt
{
    public class IpoptReconciliationProblem : IpoptProblem
    {
        private Double[] _standardDeviations;
        private Double[] _averageValues;
        private readonly JacobianHelper _jacobianHelper;
        private readonly Func<Double[], Double[]> _constraints;
        private Jacobian _jacobian;
        private readonly Action<IterationResult> _callback;
        private Boolean _refreshJac;
        private Int32 _jacobianEvaluationFrequency;

        public SolverResult Solve(Double[] averageValues, Double[] standardDeviations)
        {
            return this.Solve(averageValues, standardDeviations, averageValues.Clone() as Double[]);
        }

        public SolverResult Solve(Double[] averageValues, Double[] standardDeviations, Double[] initialValues)
        {
            Double obj;
            this._averageValues = averageValues;
            this._standardDeviations = standardDeviations;
            var code = this.SolveProblem(initialValues, out obj);
            var result = new SolverResult(initialValues, (Int32)code);
            return result;
        }

        #region IpoptProblem methods override

        public override IpoptBoolType eval_f(Int32 n, Double[] x, IpoptBoolType new_x, out Double obj_value,
            IntPtr p_user_data)
        {
            //Objective function
            obj_value = x.Select((d, i) => Math.Pow((d - this._averageValues[i]) / this._standardDeviations[i], 2)).Sum();
            return IpoptBoolType.True;
        }

        public override IpoptBoolType eval_g(Int32 n, Double[] x, IpoptBoolType new_x, Int32 m, Double[] g,
            IntPtr p_user_data)
        {
            //Contstraints
            var updatedConstraints = this._constraints(x);
            for (var i = 0; i < updatedConstraints.Length; i++)
            {
                g[i] = updatedConstraints[i];
            }
            return IpoptBoolType.True;
        }

        public override IpoptBoolType eval_grad_f(Int32 n, Double[] x, IpoptBoolType new_x, Double[] grad_f,
            IntPtr p_user_data)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                grad_f[i] = 2 * ((x[i] - this._averageValues[i]) / this._standardDeviations[i]) *
                            (1 / this._standardDeviations[i]);
            }
            return IpoptBoolType.True;
        }

        public override IpoptBoolType eval_jac_g(Int32 n, Double[] x, IpoptBoolType new_x, Int32 m, Int32 nele_jac,
            Int32[] iRow, Int32[] jCol, Double[] values, IntPtr p_user_data)
        {
            if (values == null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < iRow.Length; i++)
                {
                    iRow[i] = this._jacobian.iRow[i];
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < jCol.Length; i++)
                {
                    jCol[i] = this._jacobian.jCol[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (this._refreshJac)
                {
                    this._jacobian = this._jacobianHelper.UpdateJacobian(x, this._constraints, this._jacobian);
                }
                //else
                //{
                for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = this._jacobian.values[i];
                }
                //}
            }
            return IpoptBoolType.True;
        }

        public override IpoptBoolType eval_h(Int32 n, Double[] x, IpoptBoolType new_x, Double obj_factor, Int32 m,
            Double[] lambda, IpoptBoolType new_lambda, Int32 nele_hess, Int32[] iRow, Int32[] jCol, Double[] values,
            IntPtr p_user_data)
        {
            return IpoptBoolType.True;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Intermediate callback for each iteration.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="alg_mod">The algorithm mode.</param>
        /// <param name="iter_count">The current iteration count.</param>
        /// <param name="obj_value">The unscaled objective value at the current point.</param>
        /// <param name="inf_pr">The unscaled constraint violation at the current point.</param>
        /// <param name="inf_du">The scaled dual infeasibility at the current point.</param>
        /// <param name="mu">log_10 of the value of the barrier parameter mu</param>
        /// <param name="d_norm">The infinity norm (max) of the primal step.</param>
        /// <param name="regularization_size">log_10 of the value of the regularization term for the Hessian of the Lagrangian in the augmented system. A dash (-) indicates that no regularization was done.</param>
        /// <param name="alpha_du">The step size for the dual variables for the box constraints in the equality constrained formulation.</param>
        /// <param name="alpha_pr">The step size for the primal variables  x and  lambda in the equality constrained formulation.</param>
        /// <param name="ls_trials">The number of backtracking line search steps (does not include second-order correction steps).</param>
        /// <param name="p_user_data">User data.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override IpoptBoolType intermediate(IpoptAlgorithmMode alg_mod, Int32 iter_count, Double obj_value,
            Double inf_pr, Double inf_du,
            Double mu, Double d_norm, Double regularization_size, Double alpha_du, Double alpha_pr, Int32 ls_trials,
            IntPtr p_user_data)
        {
            this._callback(new IterationResult
            {
                ObjectiveFunction = obj_value,
                IterationNumber = iter_count,
                BacktrackingLines = ls_trials,
                ConstraintViolation = inf_pr,
                DualInfeasibility = inf_du,
                DualVariablesStepSize = alpha_du,
                Mu = mu,
                PrimalStepNorm = d_norm,
                PrimalVariablesStepSize = alpha_pr,
                RegularizationTerm = regularization_size
            });
            this._refreshJac = iter_count > 0 && iter_count % this._jacobianEvaluationFrequency == 0;
            return IpoptBoolType.True;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public IpoptReconciliationProblem(JacobianHelper jacobianHelper, Double[] lowerBounds,
            Double[] upperBounds, Double[] constraintLowerBounds, Double[] constraintUpperBounds,
            Func<Double[], Double[]> constraints, Jacobian jacobian, IpoptParams ipoptParams,
            Action<IterationResult> callback)
            : base(
                lowerBounds.Length, lowerBounds, upperBounds, constraintLowerBounds.Length, constraintLowerBounds,
                constraintUpperBounds, jacobian.iRow.Length, 0, true, true, true)
        {
            this._jacobianHelper = jacobianHelper;
            this._constraints = constraints;
            this._jacobian = jacobian;
            this._callback = callback;
            this.SetOptions(ipoptParams);
        }

        #endregion

        private void SetOptions(IpoptParams ipoptParams)
        {
            this.AddOption("tol", ipoptParams.Tolerance);
            this.AddOption("max_iter", ipoptParams.MaximumIterations);
            this.AddOption("dual_inf_tol", ipoptParams.DualInfeasibilityTolerance);
            this.AddOption("constr_viol_tol", ipoptParams.ConstraintViolationTolerance);
            this.AddOption("compl_inf_tol", ipoptParams.ComplementaryInfTolerance);

            // Acceptable solution
            this.AddOption("acceptable_iter", ipoptParams.AcceptableIterationNumber);
            this.AddOption("acceptable_tol", ipoptParams.AcceptableTolerance);
            this.AddOption("acceptable_obj_change_tol", ipoptParams.AcceptableObjFctChange);
            this.AddOption("acceptable_dual_inf_tol", ipoptParams.AcceptableDualInfeasibilityTolerance);
            this.AddOption("acceptable_constr_viol_tol", ipoptParams.AcceptableConstraintViolationTolerance);

            // Initialization
            this.AddOption("bound_mult_init_val", ipoptParams.BoundMultiplier);
            this.AddOption("bound_mult_init_method", ipoptParams.BoundMultiplierInitializationMethod);
            this.AddOption("mu_init", ipoptParams.MuInit);
            this.AddOption("mu_strategy", ipoptParams.MuStrategy);
            //this.AddOption("nlp_upper_bound_inf", 1e-8);
            //this.AddOption("bound_relax_factor", 1e-4);
            //this.AddOption("nlp_scaling_min_value", 0.1);
            //this.AddOption("bound_push", 1e-16);
            //this.AddOption("bound_frac", 1e-16);

            this.AddOption("alpha_for_y", ipoptParams.AlphaForY);
            //this.AddOption("quality_function_max_section_steps",3);
            this.AddOption("recalc_y_feas_tol", ipoptParams.RecalcYFeasTol);
            this.AddOption("recalc_y", ipoptParams.RecalcY);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ipoptParams.LogFilePath))
            {
                this.OpenOutputFile(ipoptParams.LogFilePath, ipoptParams.LogLevel);
            }
            //JsonFile.Save(ipoptParams, @"d:\tmp\ipoptParams.json");

            this.AddOption("nlp_scaling_max_gradient", ipoptParams.MaxGradient);
            this.AddOption("mumps_scaling", ipoptParams.MumpsScaling);
            this._jacobianEvaluationFrequency = ipoptParams.JacFreq;
        }
    }
}
```

I then call it like this (from a console app):

```
        var dic = results.Select((d, i) => new {Name = d.TagName, Index = i})
            .ToDictionary(d => d.Name, d => d.Index);
        var avg = results.Select(d => d.AverageValue).ToArray();
        var stdDev = results.Select(d => d.StdDev).ToArray();
        var lowerBounds = results.Select(d => d.Min).ToArray();
        var upperBounds = results.Select(d => d.Max).ToArray();
        var cLowerBounds = Enumerable.Range(0, constraints).Select(d => -Double.Epsilon).ToArray();
        var cUpperBoundsBounds = cLowerBounds.Select(d => Double.Epsilon).ToArray();

        var jacobianHelper = new JacobianHelper();

        Func<Double[], Double[]> constraintCallback = values =>
        {
            var gasHpToComp = values[dic["Gas Outlet HP to Comp (kSm3/d)"]];
            var gasLpToComp = values[dic["Gas Outlet LP to Comp (kSm3/d)"]];
            var flareRecovery = values[dic["Flares Recovery"]];
            var flareLP2 = dic.ContainsKey("Gas Comp LP2 to HP Flare (kSm3/d)")
                ? values[dic["Gas Comp LP2 to HP Flare (kSm3/d)"]]
                : 0;
            var gasBeforeTeg = gasHpToComp + gasLpToComp + flareRecovery + flareLP2;
            var teg = values[dic["Gas TEG"]];
            var r1 = gasBeforeTeg - teg;

            var gasExport = values[dic["Gas Export"]];
            var hp1Flare = values[dic["Gas Comp HP1 to HP Flare"]];
            var fuelgas = values[dic["Fuel Gas"]];
            var gasLift = values[dic["Gas Lift"]];

            var gasAfterTeg = gasExport + hp1Flare + fuelgas + gasLift;

            var r2 = teg - gasAfterTeg;
            return new[] {r2, r1};
        };
        var jac = jacobianHelper.ComputeJacobian(avg, constraintCallback);

        const String fileName = "ipoptLog";
        var ipoptParams = new IpoptParams
        {
            LogLevel = 12
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            ipoptParams.LogFilePath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, $"{fileName}.{i}.txt");
            SolverResult res;
            using (var sut = new IpoptReconciliationProblem(jacobianHelper, lowerBounds, upperBounds, cLowerBounds,
                cUpperBoundsBounds, constraintCallback, jac, ipoptParams, ir => { }))
            {
                res = sut.Solve(avg, stdDev);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Resolution " + i + " - result: " + res.ReturnCode);
        }
```

On a side note (but maybe related?), the same problem converges in a unit test and in a console app, but not in a Windows Service or in WebAPI.

The full, runnable code is available in a [repository](https://github.com/Ledragon/IpoptTest) (VS2017), demonstrating the unreproducible results.

Any hint or guidance would be appreciated. I am by no means an expert in optimization problems, even less in IPOPT.

**Edit**
The `Dispose` method in the IPOPT interface is as follow:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!m_disposed)
            {
                if (m_problem != IntPtr.Zero)
                    IpoptAdapter.FreeIpoptProblem(m_problem);

                if (disposing)
                {
                    m_problem = IntPtr.Zero;
                }

                m_disposed = true;
            }
        }
```

This seems to free the problem itself, but not the solver.

Comment: It is unlikely people will open an external repo. It would be more helpful to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve as part of your question.

Comment: No optimization expert as well. Just to get this clear: the result is dependent of the state of the process?  Iteration 0...x gives only the same result when you restart the process?

Comment: @mjwills I updated my question with code, I hope this is helpful

Comment: @Stefan it seems to be yes. every time the process is restarted, iteration 0 consistently gives the same results.

Comment: Ok, thats quite a lot :) ... possible subjects are: all inputs: make sure you don't use them for temporary storage. All objects with the `IDisposable` interface (I can't tell which ones that are, but for every object which has this interface the `Dispose` funciton must be called if your done with it). The most likely suspect is the `IntPtr p_user_data`, where do you get it from? And it is something that needs to be freed.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that... I tried the loop with the declaration of the input variables inside as well, with exactly the same results. The only `IDisposable` object is `IpoptReconciliationProblem`, implemented in the base class `IpoptProblem`. The base class frees the problem and sets references to `IntPtr.Zero`, but does not act on `p_user_data`, which is a variable provided by the external solver in the callbacks only, and not referenced anywhere in the code as a member field

Comment: After breaking in the code, `p_user_data` is always equal to `IntPtr.Zero`

Comment: Ok, another (maybe silly) question: how do you load/fill `results`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159569/discussion-between-hugues-stefanski-and-stefan).

Comment: Can someone clarify why is this question tagged [COM]? Even if the library runs through COM (it doesn't look like it does), the problem statement doesn't seem to be related to COM interop. It also doesn't seem to be about serial ports, a common cause of mistagging.

Comment: @EuroMicelli I added the tag as I think this is due to a missing release of resources in the COM interfacing of IPOPT in c#; I removed the tag, but let me know if this explanation justifies adding it back

Comment: So, the IPOPT interface is COM-based? It doesn't look it from the code sample. If you think the problem might be COM related, I would make sure the relevant code is present, and then I would point out the code and the concern explicitly; then put the tag back. We're just trying to get the right people to see the question.